# How to change border color of radio button in Material-UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change outer ring of Material UI radio button.

https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/

Right now I have this:

[image: Radio button 1]

But what I would like to get is

[image: Radio button 2]

I have tried to style `PrivateRadioButtonIcon-layer` class in blue, and `MuiSvgIcon-root` in black, but I can't find a way to style `PrivateRadioButtonIcon-layer`

Comment: @sinanspd I am using ```createMuiTheme``` I am pretty sure ```::ng-deep``` is an angular thing

Comment: my bad. For some reason, my brain defaulted to angular, realized question was on React. Deleted the comment. Apologies..

Comment: @Oskars The radio buttons are svg icons. Both of the classes you mentioned (`PrivateRadioButtonIcon-layer` and `MuiSvgIcon-root`) target the same element which is an svg element. The blue is the fill color. In order to have the outer ring be black and thinner than it currently is, you'll need to create a custom svg icon and use that via the `icon` and `checkedIcon` [props](https://material-ui.com/api/radio/#props). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323136/error-when-using-custom-icon-for-switch-component/60324777#60324777) for an example of using a custom icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I describe two solutions (both applicable to MUI v5):

1. **CSS-only** solution to change the color of border and circle separately.
2. Solution with **custom icon** in order to design it as you please.

### CSS only solution

If you only want to change the border color as stated in the question title  (and not the thickness of the border) you can do the following in **MUI 5** (via the `sx` prop):

1. Style the border via the selector `'& .MuiSvgIcon-root:not(.MuiSvgIcon-root ~ .MuiSvgIcon-root)'` which uses the CSS [general siblings combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to only select the first occurance of the `MuiSvgIcon-root` class.
2. Style the circle via the selector `'& .MuiSvgIcon-root + .MuiSvgIcon-root'` which uses the CSS [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`) to access the second svg.

Entire code of Radio button:

```
<Radio
    {...otherRadioProps}
    sx={{
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root:not(.MuiSvgIcon-root ~ .MuiSvgIcon-root)':
            {
                color: 'red',
            },
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root + .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
            color: 'blue',
        },
    }}
/>
```

**Notes**:

1. **Thickness** of border: We cannot make the border thinner (as your design suggests) but we can make the border thicker via CSS alone. We have to access the `path` element inside the SVG of the surrounding border of the radio button. Add the following to the `sx` prop:

   ```
   '& .MuiSvgIcon-root:not(.MuiSvgIcon-root ~ .MuiSvgIcon-root) path':
       {
           stroke: 'red',
           strokeWidth: 3,
       },
   ```

   [image: Radio button with thick border]

   Note that you need the `stroke: 'red',` line even though you set `color: 'red'` on the `.MuiSvgIcon-root` element.
2. We cannot target the circle directly with a class name because Material UI gives the border and the circle the same class name as you can see in this screenshot from Firefox DevTools:

   [image: DOM representation of both SVG elements of the radio buttons]

### Solution with custom `icon` and `checkedIcon` component

If you want a thinner border you have to add own SVG icons via the `icon` and `checkedIcon` props. To get the following:

[image]

you can use the following icon component:

```
const RadioButton = ({ checked }) => (
    <svg
        width="38px"
        height="38px"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        fontSize="38px">
        <circle
            cx="50%"
            cy="50%"
            r="11px"
            stroke="red"
            stroke-width="1px"
            fill="none"
        />
        {checked && (
            <circle
                cx="50%"
                cy="50%"
                r="6px"
                fill="blue"
            />
        )}
    </svg>
);
```

and use it in your MUI `Radio` component like this:

```
<Radio
    icon={<RadioButton />}
    checkedIcon={<RadioButton checked />}
    {...otherProps}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - This is material UI tag which you are using:-

```
<FormControlLabel value="" control={<Radio />} label="" />
```

2 - give className to it and also style on Radio tag like this:-

```
<FormControlLabel className="targetInsideOfRadio" value="" control={<Radio style={{color:"#979797"}} />} label="" />
```

3 - go to custom.css file and add like this:-

```
.targetInsideOfRadio > span > span > div > svg ~ svg > path {
     color: #2149b9;
 }
```

4 - Hope you get the Answer :)